# Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL (Android)

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView with custom WebViewClient class, which allowed me to react to user's clicks on links inside the WebView and process them.
Here's the code:

```
class WebViewClickClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String note = "";
        String note_id = new String(url);
        if (note_id.contains("#")) {
            int offset = note_id.indexOf("#");
            note_id = note_id.substring(offset + 1, note_id.length());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bookNotes.size(); i++) {
            if (bookNotes.get(i).noteId().equals(note_id)) {
                note = bookNotes.get(i).noteSection();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!note.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), note, LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Now it's not working anymore and the WebViewClient's methods aren't even triggered upon click. Instead I get this message: `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL:"`

Do I need to handle this with JavaScript now or is there any workaround with WebView for Android?

**UPDATE:**
For anyone interested in workaround with JS Interface here's how I made it.

The logic for reacting to user clicks moved from the `onPageFinished` method to

```
private class JSInterface {
public void showToast(String key) {...}
}
```

Then, WebView is created as follows:

```
WebView book_view;
book_view = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_text_view);
book_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

book_view.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "JAVA_CODE");
```

`JAVA_CODE` object will be called from JavaScript code which has to be added dynamically to each WebView "page" by concatenating text contents with JS and calling `loadData()` method on the WebView.

```
StringBuilder j_script = new StringBuilder();
if (note_ids.size() > 0) {
    j_script.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nfunction jscallback()\n{");
    for (int i = 0; i < note_ids.size(); i++) {
         j_script.append("var dv" + i + " = document.getElementById(\"" + note_ids.get(i) + "\");\ndv" + i + ".onclick = function() {JAVA_CODE.showToast(\"" + note_ids.get(i) + "\")};\n");
    }
    j_script.append("}</script>");
}
```

Comment: At the current moment I got away with JavaScript interface, but that's definitely added complexity and fragility to the code.

Comment: can you share your solution?

Comment: @SaeedJassani please see the original post update.